# Responsive / CSS fixed and variable widths

Tags: html, css

CSS and responsiveness in multiple columns with fixed and scaleable elements can be done in many ways.

I have created a solution that seems to work, though I have no idea whether this is best practice.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brandrally/ZDt6N/)

CSS

```css
html, body { margin:0 auto; padding:0;  background: #fff; text-align: center; }

/* Clearfix
============================================================================ */
.CF { display:inline-block;overflow:hidden; }

/* Elements
============================================================================ */
div#container {max-width: 1140px;  min-width: 960px; margin:0 auto; margin-top: 10px; padding:0;  background:#0F9;  position:relative;}
    div#left-menu {width: 100px; background:#F30; position: absolute; top:0; left:0;   }
    div#information {padding: 10px 10px 25px 10px; background:#39C;  margin-left:100px;}
        div#information-wrapper {position:relative; background:#3FF; }
            div#information-left-menu {width: 125px;  background:#C30; position: absolute; top: 0; left:0;}
            div#content {background:#FC0; margin-left: 125px; text-align:left;}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="container" class="CF" >

    <!-- This is fixed Width -->
    <div id="left-menu">
    <p>Left 100px wide </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Width scales to size of Container -->
    <div id="information" class="CF">
        <div id="information-wrapper">
            <div id="information-left-menu">Fixed width of 125px </div>
            <div id="content">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

</div><!-- / END / Container / -->
```

Comment: It's not really a responsive layout if you need to scroll horizontally on a viewport that's less than 960px wide, is it?

Comment: `/* IE mac \*/` <- Are there actually people using IE for Mac?  Does IE even work on OSX?

Comment: @Dagg It's responsive if it adjusts to browser size. I am  trying to understand best practice of fixed width and scalable columns.

Comment: @cimmanon Good point. That doesn't really need to be there.

Comment: @Dagg That's not what "responsive" means in the context of web design.  What you have is liquid and that's it.  That's been around forever.  Also, please refrain from modifying your code once you get some actual reviews, as it will invalidate the answers.

Comment: @cimmanon "Responsive web design (RWD) is a web design approach aimed at crafting sites to provide an optimal viewing experience—easy reading and navigation with a **minimum of resizing, panning, and scrolling** — across a wide range of devices (from **mobile phones** to desktop computer monitors)." --[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

Comment: @cimmanon a liquid layout could certainly be considered a "responsive design" under the right conditions. These just aren't the right conditions.

Comment: @cimmanon Last Mac version of Internet Explorer for Mac was released [in 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_for_Mac). So _technically_ IE does work on OS X - if that OS X is a decade old :P (those were fun times by the way; despite it being named Internet Explorer and being made by Microsoft, IE/Mac was completely different from IE/Win, and in turn completely different from any other browser... ugh)

Comment: @Dagg Whoops, my bad.  I meant it in response to the OP.  I agree with you: a responsive design should adapt to fit any viewport size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a responsive web design, you need to do more than have no horizontal scrolling when viewed with a desktop browser.  You have to adapt to the viewport of any device, from the really small (phone) to the really big (desktop).  This code does not, sorry.

Responsive web design is typically achieved by using media queries (there are other ways, but they're unavailable in IE versions older than 10), which are completely absent from your code.  I suggest you take the time to learn about what responsive web design is:

- http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/
- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/
- http://thesiteslinger.com/blog/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/
- http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

That said, there are other things that are not good here:

- **Absolute positioning of the "left menu".**  In general, absolute positioning should be avoided unless it is absolutely necessary (eg. drop menus, etc.).  Absolutely positioned elements can become *cut off* if there's not enough surrounding content to prevent it from overflowing its ancestor elements.  Multi-column layouts can easily be done using floats or the table display properties (eg. `display: table-cell`) and the content won't get cut off.
- **Using px to restrict the width of text containing elements.**  If the user needs to increase their font-size for accessibility reasons, 100-125px is no longer an appropriate sized container for that text.  You should be using ems or other relative units instead.
- **No semantic markup.**  With HTML5 (see: http://html5doctor.com/), a whole slew of new semantic container elements have been added (eg. article, nav, aside, section) which may or may not be more appropriate than the general purpose div (I can't tell because there's no real content here).  Markup should be chosen to describe the content *first*, then you can worry about how to make it pretty.

Comment: really appreciate your input and thoughts. Thank you for taking the time to respond to this topic.